# Hide HTML element based on CSS class after specified duration

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to unhide all elements inside certain class on a webpage according to a chosen time written in the class.

For example:

- `class=".unhide15"` should unhide the element after 15 seconds.
- `class=".unhide123"` should unhide the element after 123 seconds.

And so on..

I arrived to this code below *(it works)*, but I still can't chose any time I want.

```html
<style>
    .unhide15, .unhide30, .unhide60{
      display:none;
    }
</style>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.unhide15'), function (el) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    });
}, 15000);

setTimeout(function(){
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.unhide30'), function (el) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    });
}, 30000);

setTimeout(function(){
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.unhide60'), function (el) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    });
}, 60000);
</script>
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: You can change the timeout duration, isn't it?

Comment: class=".unhide15" has a dot which should be removed. Your code should be OK then. Using your browser dev tools inspect facility should have shown you a JS error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I would use only one class... Along with a data attribute to hold the desired time.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".unhide").forEach(function (elem) {
  let delay = parseInt(elem.getAttribute("data-time")) * 1000;
  setTimeout(function () {
    elem.style.display = "block";
  }, delay);
});
```

```css
.unhide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="unhide" data-time="1">Hello!</div>
<div class="unhide" data-time="3">Hello!</div>
<div class="unhide" data-time="10">Hello!</div>
<div class="unhide" data-time="12">Hello!</div>
```

=== **EDIT**

Since you cannot add `data-` attributes... You can have an array (on the JS side) to do the same thing about time values. Just make sure to have all them... And in order.

```js
// Set a time array for each element (in order)
let time_array = [
  1, 3, 10, 12 // seconds
];

document.querySelectorAll(".unhide").forEach(function (elem, index) {
  let delay = time_array[index] * 1000;
  setTimeout(function () {
    elem.style.display = "block";
  }, delay);
});
```

```css
.unhide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="unhide">Hello!</div>
<div class="unhide">Hello!</div>
<div class="unhide">Hello!</div>
<div class="unhide">Hello!</div>
```

Comment: Awesome answer, Louys! In this case I'm using the wordpress Elementor Free, and sadly data-attributes are not an option :/ so the only thing I can work with are Classes...

Comment: Just to make sure... I edited my answer. Have a look. ;)